# mysql_fetch_assoc supplied argumment

Tags: php, mysql

i'm very new in php mysql programming. i have write program for retrieving my users profile information, but showed me

> mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid on line 9 and 21

here is my code. but on the other hand it's working on another database. i edited single quotes but it still give the same error message. can you please give me a solution or if you have like this program made by your own it will be more helpful to compare and identify my lacking's.

```
<?php
include ("config.php")
?>

<?php
 function getUsersData($id)
 {
    $array=array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'id' = '" . $id );
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $array['id']=$row ['id'];
        $array['name']=$row ['name'];
        $array['username']=$row ['username'];
        $array['email']=$row ['email'];
    }
    return $array;
 }
 function getId($username)
 {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT 'id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '" . $username . "'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        return $row['id'];
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You didn't correctly quote the `$id` value, and incorrectly quoted the column name. Add mysql_error(), then read up on PDO / parameter binding.

Comment: First of all, stop using `mysql` functions, since it's deprecated (what means somewhere in the future it will be kicked out of php and your code won't work anymore). Use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: MySql query is not right here . so the $result not getting the resource id. As a new developer i suggest you to print your query before execute . 


The line 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'id' = '" . $id );

should be 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '" . $id ."'");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because the query failed. Identifier (tables/columns) quotes are backticks not single quotes:

```
`users`
```

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'id' = '" . $id ); // fix the quoting here
                                     ^     ^       ^  ^
```

Either you include them or omit them.

```
$id = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id");
```

Obligatory Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: My question Limit is done !  I am trying to update my data and i wrote this code but its not working  Code is .. if (isset($_POST['steup'])){

$deposit_id = $_POST['deposit_id'];
$deposit_amount= $_POST['deposit_amount'];
$deposit_percentage = $_POST['deposit_percentage'];
$deposit_paystatus = 1;

$sql1 = " UPDATE tbl_deposit SET deposit_amount = '$deposit_amount',  deposit_percentage = '$deposit_percentage', deposit_paystatus = '$ deposit_paystatus' WHERE deposit_id = '$deposit_id' ";
$result = $db->query($sql1);

}
where is the problem please help me